# MySQL: Reference current row in delete trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-delete

I'm having trouble referencing the current row in an `AFTER DELETE` trigger in MySQL. Pretend I have the following `books` table:

```
+----+------+----------+
| id | name | ordering |
+----+------+----------+
| 1  | It   | 3        |
| 2  | Cujo | 1        |
| 3  | Rage | 2        |
+----+------+----------+
```

I want to create a trigger that will decrement all rows whose `ordering` value is greater than the `ordering` value in a row that is deleted. For example, if I do `DELETE FROM books WHERE id = 2`, I want the resulting table to look like:

```
+----+------+----------+
| id | name | ordering |
+----+------+----------+
| 1  | It   | 2        |
| 3  | Rage | 1        |
+----+------+----------+
```

I've tried:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS reorder_books_on_delete;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER reorder_books_on_delete 
AFTER DELETE ON books 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    IF ordering > OLD.ordering 
    THEN 
        UPDATE books SET ordering = ordering - 1 
        WHERE id = id;
    END IF; 
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But this results in an error when I execute a `DELETE` on the table:

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'ordering' in 'where clause'

This refers to the `if` statement, so how do I reference the current row in an `ON DELETE` trigger? The column definitely does exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it fails is because there is no `current` row and hence, `ordering` column doesn't exist, it should be used in `WHERE` clause, like this:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS reorder_books_on_delete;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER reorder_books_on_delete 
AFTER DELETE ON books 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
     UPDATE books SET ordering = ordering - 1 
     WHERE ordering > OLD.ordering;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

However, as per MySQL's [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html), you can't do this, it will return the following error:

> SQL Error (1442): Can't update table 'books' in stored
>   function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked
>   this stored function/trigger.

So, you will have to run another `UPDATE` query after `DELETE` query in a single transaction to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

As said by Darshan, you can't do this with a Trigger.... But, Procedure can make if for you !

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS delete_book;
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE delete_book(IN pId INT)
BEGIN
    set @a = (
        SELECT ordering
        FROM books
        WHERE id = pId
        );

    UPDATE books SET ordering = ordering - 1 
    WHERE ordering  > @a;

    delete from books
    WHERE id = pId;

END 
//
DELIMITER ;
```

And you just have, instead of your `DELETE FROM books WHERE id = 4` to make a `CALL delete_book(4);`